# Rendering stereoscopy 3D in OpenGL ES 3.0 or 2.0 Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, render, stereoscopy

I am working with 3D objects and I'm using OpenGL ES for Android. What I am trying to do is to implement two `GLES20.glViewport()` so I can have the same object twice, one in the left and one in the right. I've seen tutorials for OpenGL and C++, and this is possible. But in Android it is different, because I need to call `GLES20.glViewport()` in the `onSurfaceChanged()` method. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: You can call `GLES20.glViewport()` anywhere, if you have a valid and current OpenGL context. So you can call it before you draw the geometry.

Comment: Yes! You're right, yesterday I finally did it. Sorry I didn't close this or wrote an answer. I'll put my solution for others to read it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know now how to do this. If someone wants to implement this then here is my solution.

1.- Define your glViewPort() in onSurfaceChanged() method. This can have the full resolution of your screen.

2.- In the method that draws your left object put at the top of it:

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
GLES20.glScissor(0, 0, width/2, height);
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height);
```

Then all that is needed for drawing, and finally at the end of the method you disable the scissor test.

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

3.- You do the same for the right object, but changing the parameters of the functions.

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
GLES20.glScissor(width/2, 0, width/2, height);
GLES20.glViewport(width/2, 0, width/2, height);
...
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```